# How many read or write file descriptors will be there in total?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc, system-calls

```
main() {
    int fd1[2],fd2[2];
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    fork(); 
    fork();
}
```

How many read or write file descriptors will be there in total in the above code? How many pipes would be created in total? What all data will be copied on to the child processes from their respective parent processes? Please explain the working of the program too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `fork();` creates one child; the second `fork();` is run by the father and the child, so you get one second child and a grandchild. So in all you get 4 processes.

Each process has 7 opened FDs : 0,1,2 plus `fd1[0,1]` plus `fd2[0,1]`). Thus there are 7 times 4 = 28 opened fds.

Note that calling `fork` without checking error/child/father is a very bad idea !

See the output of one of the 4 running processes using `lsof -p <pid>` :

```
a.out   13147 thiel    0u   CHR  136,1      0t0       4 /dev/pts/1
a.out   13147 thiel    1u   CHR  136,1      0t0       4 /dev/pts/1
a.out   13147 thiel    2u   CHR  136,1      0t0       4 /dev/pts/1
a.out   13147 thiel    3r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 1143532 pipe
a.out   13147 thiel    4w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 1143532 pipe
a.out   13147 thiel    5r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 1143533 pipe
a.out   13147 thiel    6w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 1143533 pipe
```

Comment: Would the stdin, stdout and stderr be there in all the four processes?

Comment: You can see the output of lsof above for one process. The same for each of the four processes since the two childs and the grandchild inherit the file descriptors table from the father. Of course you can't see this in your code because your program stops just after the second fork; just add a sleep(60) at the end to let them live a little longer.